# Angular 7: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using angular7 and following the step as  the exact example here
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/171/Angular-7-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-7-by-Example

But getting the error data doesn't. Here is the error below:

```
src/app/home/home.component.html:18:29 - error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'.

18     <li *ngFor="let user of users.data">
                               ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/home/home.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.
```

I am trying to test the code and generate the service but i keep getting  errors in home.component.html
home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  users: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data
      console.log(this.users)
    })
  }

}
```

home.component.html

```
<ul *ngIf="users">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users.data"> 
      <!-- <img [src]="user.avatar">
      <p>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p> -->
      <p> {{user}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users');
  }

}
```

this is the exact code as the example..how can this be resolved?

Comment: What `console.log` result do you get from the data from the `getUsers()` method?

Answer (score 2):

Define type for the user object like below.

```
user: {
   data: any;
}
```

Then initialize user object with and empty array in HomeComponent.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
users: any;
```

or make sure User, Data Object

```
export class User {
 bla : string,
 data : Array<Data>
}

export class Data{
 blabla : string,
 blablabla : number
}
```

something like this

then

```
users : User = new User()
```

i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a compilation issue, not a runtime issue. What this means is that there is likely an issue with your typesafety enforced by Typescript.

We can see that you've typesafed `users` as `Object`. However, `data` does not exist on the generic class `Object`. What you can do is just cast `users` differently.

```js
users: {
  data: {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
  }[];
}
```

So as you can see we're describing an object called `users` with a property `data`. `data` is an array of objects (`{}[]`) that contain a `first_name` and `last_name` property.